# Django get count of related objects with value and add it to an annotation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

If I want to annotate the number of related objects to each parent object, I would do this:

```
Agent.objects.annotate(deal_count=Count('deal'))
```

If my `Deal` objects have a `closed` boolean, how would I annotate the number of deals marked as closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [**`filter=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter-1):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Agent.objects.annotate(deal_count=Count('deal', filter=Q(deal__closed=True)))
```

or if you want to annotate with both counts:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Agent.objects.annotate(
    deal_count=Count('deal'),
    closed_deal_count=Count('deal', filter=Q(deal__closed=True))
)
```